# Using Chrome text-to-speech in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

Now, here's a [demo of a chrome app](https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=5KL_ccQwAuo) that uses the chrome text-to-speech engine.

And, [here's the source](https://github.com/petele/ChromeTTS)
I've modified this app to work as an 'extension' instead of an app.
But, the tts is not available it seems.
I've added 'tts' under 'permissions' in my **manifest file**.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Text2Speech",
  "version": "1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon_16.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["tts"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "js/app.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And, here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("keypress", function(e) { 
    if ( e.shiftKey && ( e.keyCode === 108 || e.keyCode === 76) ) {
      console.log( "You pressed SHIFT + L" , $(prevElement).text());
      saySomething($(prevElement).text());
    }
  });
});
var prevElement = null;
document.addEventListener('mousemove',
  function(e){
      var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
      if (prevElement!= null) {prevElement.classList.remove("mouseOn");}
      elem.classList.add("mouseOn");
      prevElement = elem;
  },true);

function saySomething(toSay) {
  chrome.tts.speak(toSay, { rate: 0.8, onEvent: function(event) {}}, function(evt) {});
}
```

I am getting an error in `saySomething` method.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speak' of undefined`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts, content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:

Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:

- extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )
- i18n
- runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
- storage

You may want to send a message from your content script to your background page as documented at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple

```js
// content script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({toSay: "hello Vikram"}, function() {});

// background page
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
  chrome.tts.speak(request.toSay, 
                  { rate: 0.8, onEvent: function(event) {}}, function() {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This did it for me. But, now I'm facing another problem. The extension works fine on my development machine. But, doesn't work on other machines. As soon as, I drag and drop the packed extension on `chrome://extensions` window, it installs it but disables it immediately- saying that the only extensions downloaded from Web Store will work. [In order to run an extension that has been turned off, use a pre-release version of chrome.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2811969?p=ui_remove_non_cws_extensions&rd=1&hl=en).Can you suggest some work around for this?

Comment: If you can, simply load the unpacked extension folder into chrome (not the crx).

Comment: This is was my initial plan. But, then when you've an unpacked extension added to chrome in developer mode, every time you launch chrome it gives you a warning message something like, 'An unpacked third-party extension has been added to your browser. Would you like to disable it?'
So not really a clean solution that can be released to the user!

Comment: If you want to share your Extension, I recommend the Chrome Web Store. See https://developer.chrome.com/webstore.

Comment: It was a customized solution for a client for internal use within the organization. So, I didn't publish it on the web store.

Comment: You can still deploy crx in your organization in one of three ways: via group policy, the registry, or via master_preferences. See https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use chrome.tts from your background page and not in a content script.

see this for an example: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#speak-selection